# answer inline query in telegram game bot doesn't work

Tags: php, bots, telegram, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

when i type bot's username in a chat screen, inline mode works but it doesn't show the list of my games (result parameter). what is the problem?

```
$message= file_get_contents("php://input");
$arrayMessage= json_decode($message, true);
$inlinequeryId = $arrayMessage['inline_query']['id'];
$reply_markup     = array(
    'inline_keyboard' => array(
        array(
            array( 'text' => 'start game', 'callback_game' => 'it starts the game' )
        )
    )
);

$inlineResult = array(
    'type'=>'game',
    'id' =>$inlinequeryId,
    'game_short_name' => 'cuttherope',
    'replay_markup' => $reply_markup
);
$inlineResult = json_encode($inlineResult);

$url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot" . $token . "/answerInlineQuery?inline_query_id=" . $inlinequeryId . "&results=" . $inlineResult;
file_get_contents( $url );
```

Comment: Did you set webhook?

Comment: Check the botfather setting, the inline query feedback must be 100 %

Comment: Use this maybe the http query is not encoded correctly due to json : `$url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot" . $token . "/answerInlineQuery?".http_build_query("inline_query_id"=>$inlinequeryId, "results" =>$inlineResult);`